# Is there a race condition when using IHttpClientFactory and different BaseUrl? ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpclient, race-condition

A named `HttpClient` is registered in `Startup.cs` as `services.AddHttpClient("MainClient")`.

The `HttpClient` is used like this in different places:

```
var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MainClient");
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_customUrl);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CustomHeader", _customHeader);
var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(...);
```

The properties `_customUrl` and `_customHeader` vary in different places.

Is there a potential race condition when the `httpClient` is used in different HTTP-requests (or in parallel in multithreading) simultaneously with different `BaseAddress` and `DefaultRequestHeaders`?

Is there a way to avoid the race condition? Should `lock/semaphoreslim` be used in each code parts when httpClient is used?

Comment: `HttpClient` and `IHttpClientFactory` are both very thread-safe. There are no race-conditions to be concerned about.

Comment: Provided you don't mutate your `HttpClient` instance (i.e. change any of its properties like `DefaultRequestHeaders`) then you'll be fine. However because `HttpClient` instances are mutable they are not really meant to be shared by different parent/owner/containing objects because of the _risk_ of poorly designed code doing something silly like mutating a shared instance.  When you use `IHttpClientFactory` then `HttpClient` instances **are super cheap** (due to the factory's inner handler pooling and recycling) so there is no reason to share them.